# "Nice" as a response to a negative story

Tags: phrase-usage

We all know that "Nice" means "pleasant" but when a friend is telling a story about something negative happening often the response is "Nice."

Example: Person 1: So this woman got the wrong coffee from the barista and just TOTALLY went off the rails and started screaming at the employees and customers in the coffee shop.

Person 2: Nice. (shakes head in disapproval)

How can that response be defined properly and what is the appropriate label for the type of response that it is? Facetious? Sarcastic? Sardonic? What?

Comment: This is something that happens often? Maybe **ironic**?

Comment: @Evan Yes, it does.

Comment: @lly Seems mean-spirited. Heh, I was writing my comment as your answer posted.

Comment: @Evan There are worse and more gendered words for it than mean-spirited but that's a nice word for it, yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> [*Something bad*]
>
> Nice [*shaking head in disapproval*]

is textbook **irony**. If it's intended to be biting or bitter rather than resigned, it can also be called **sarcastic** or **sardonic**. If it's mocking a third person who believes or might be claimed to believe that it is nice despite its obviously not being so, it also functions as **satire** or **parody**.

Comment: Yep another friend suggested "Verbal Irony". After researching that term I realized this is likely what it is. Thanks for your answer. Nailed it. :)